# Getting User Birthday HTTP Request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor

Im trying to get birthday on the server side of my app.

I have already the `["user_birthday"]` permission on my login request.

But now on the server i need to do something like this i guess.

```
userBirtdhay = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=birthday&" + user.services.facebook.id;
```

But this results something like.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=birthday&10146450841965723dffsadf
```

And if you go to the url you get a

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

After Some research got that the `me` space on the url should be my accessToken so i try with .

```
https://graph.facebook.com/longAccesToken?fields=birthday&
```

But it returns now.

```
"message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be correct:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=birthday&access_token=[your-user-token]
```

You should start reading the Facebook docs about Access Tokens and API endpoints. You can test the API with the [API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dbirthday&).